# Uninstall Chrome silently using Powershell

Tags: powershell, uninstallation, silent

I have the following PowerShell script, which I am using to get the uninstall string for Google Chrome, and then I want to uninstall it silently. Line 3 in the script will pop up the GUI uninstaller (so it seems like everything is correct thus far), but if I add "/qn" or "/quiet" to the argument list, the uninstall doesn't seem to run at all, even if I let it sit for a couple hours.

What am I missing?

```
    $AppName = "Google Chrome"
    $Chrome = Get-ChildItem -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall, HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall | Get-ItemProperty | Where-Object {$_.DisplayName -match $($AppName)}
    Start-Process -Wait -FilePath MsiExec.exe -Argumentlist "/X",$Chrome.UninstallString.TrimStart("MsiExec.exe /X")
```

Answer (score 4):

If it's an msi you can use uninstall-package:

```
get-package *chrome* | uninstall-package -whatif
```

Comment: this certainly is a good approach but I'd be careful using *s :)

Comment: Why? You cannot state something like this without explaining it!  ;-)

Comment: @Jawad In case more than one thing matches.  Ok, I added `-whatif`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of trying to use /X and remove /X and other things, try the following

```
# Get the key to uninstall
$chromeUninstall = $Chrome.Pspath.Split("\")[-1]

Start-Process -Wait -FilePath MsiExec.exe -Argumentlist "/X $ChromeUninstall /quiet /norestart"
```

or even simpler would be,

```
Start-Process -Wait cmd.exe -ArgumentList "/c msiexec /X $ChromeUninstall /quiet /norestart"
```

`/c` - Carries out the command specified by string and then terminates

---

**Note**

On my system I get two uninstall strings. You might want to think about looping or selecting first one in the list with the use of `[0]`

Comment: Your first example throws a few errors.  Using your second example looks like it starts a "Windows Installer" process in Task Manager, but still returns to the command prompt more or less right away, and doesn't seem to uninstall Chrome.  I'm curious, what does the "/c" do?

Comment: @Andrew Updated my answer. Instead of using UninstallString, use the PSPath to get the key to use for uninstall.

Comment: No improvement, unfortunately.  Same as before, it starts a Windows installer process and returns to the command prompt pretty much right away, but doesn't seem to do anything, even after waiting a while.

Comment: Ok, I think admin rights had something to do with this, even though my username is in the local admin group on this PC.  I simplified one of your suggestions to "cmd.exe /c $Chrome.UninstallString /Passive", and noticed a UAC prompt when it ran.  I then changed /Passive to /qn and opened the Powershell ISE as admin, and it removed Chrome quickly and easily.  Thanks again for the help!